# I would like to De-Duplicate of data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud

I used data-relationship and data filter to filter a DE with order information and would like to apply it in Journey.

However, I need to de-dulpicate of contact but don't want to use SQL query or set up "No Re-entry" in Journey builder.

Does any directly way to de-duplicate contact record in DE before i choose it as entry source in Journey?

Comment: Probably not what you are looking for, but besides SQL, SSJS can do the trick. What I do not quite understand is, if its order related, why do you have to deduplicate? Also, if its just a one time send, you can use the deduplicate feature at send time.

Answer (score 0):

There is no out of the box way to achieve this. De-duplication is only available for user-initiated sends because it's like a "batch" send making the logic behind easy to apply a de-duplication.

Journeys are more a one-to-one sends, that's why this functionality is not available. Also, I've checked with our Salesforce Account Manager and it seems that this is not a feature we're going to see in the near future..

**This leaves you with two options:**

**1-** Use SQL AFTER creating your filtered DE. You'll have to do this every time you create a new audience

OR

**2**- Add a Priority field to your main DE in your Data Model and create the logic behind using SQL to populate this field with the proper value.

For example, you can use an order by on the LastModifiedDate, CreationDate,.. to populate the Priority field with a value of 1, 2, 3,.. And then add the Priority you want in your Data Filter. This way, you'll only have to develop this once and use it on all your Data Filters.